# Error when importing View

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to import View from one Drupal 7 Environment (from local to
pantheon one) and got this error:

```
- Field handler views_entity_commerce_order.operations_dropbutton is not available
- Unable to import view.
```

Any ideas what is going on here ?

Comment: Where are you Exporting the view from? Check to see if the original site has additional views modules than the site you are trying to Import to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround by setting this option in View Import:

`Bypass view validation`

Answer (score 1):

Create a field with machine name 'views_entity_commerce_order' in the pantheon one and then import your view.

Answer (score 0):

Arun has provided the correct answer above but may not be providing enough information for people who are new to Drupal, new comers simply may not know how to "create a machine field name" so hopefully this will help. The whole point of creating a View is to display some sort of list or collection of a given content type, this is usually a custom content type but it doesn't have to be. If you try to import the View before you have added all the fields to the content type you are creating the View for, you will get an error similar to the one Michal got. You should always create (or import) the View after you've finished creating your custom content type or finished modifying an existing one, and make absolutely sure you use the same field names you used in your development environment or the View Import will fail.